# *ngFor y *ngIf en misma etiqueta no funciona

Tags: array, angular, typescript, ngfor

Hola estoy creando una tabla avanzada que debe tener en el ultimo `<td>` un dropdown dinámico que tendrá unas opciones o otras dependiendo que del estado del registro(otro campo del registro actual).

La tabla en si es un subcomponente totalmente dinámico para que pueda ser reutilizado en cualquier parte de la aplicación por lo que recibe una serie de arrays con los valores necesarios para su construcción.

Dado que es bastante compleja solo pondré el código que esta relacionado con esto.

- Por un lado tenemos(recibe) un array con los datos
- Por otro un array con las claves de los campos que vamos a utilizar del primer array y el nombre visible.
- por otro(lo que nos ocupa) un array que por un lado nos indica la clave del array de datos se va utilizar para el control de acciones de estado y dentro del mismo array otro array con cada estado y si sus opciones:

  ```
    arrayOpciones = {  clave: "miestado", tipos: { estado1: { 0: { texto: "Ver", accion: "" } },
                                                   estado2: { 0: { texto: "Ver/Editar", accion: "" }, 1: { texto: "Eliminar",accion: "" } },
                                                   estado3: { 0: { texto: "Ver/Procesar", accion: "" } }, } };
  ```

Lo que tengo es que en cada pasada del `*nfor` compruebe que estado tiene y monte al final el dropdown con las opciones correspondientes.

Hasta ahora probe esto pero no me va:

componente de tablas:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let miRegistro of misdatos>
<td *ngFor="let miIndice of misIndices">{{miRegistro[miIndice.miclave]}}</td>
<td>
    <div class="d-inline-block btn-sesion" ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown">
        <button class="btn btn btn-secondary" id="dropdown1" ngbDropdownAnchor (focus)="mmiDrop.open()">opciones</button>
            <div *ngFor="let tipo of opcionesReData['tipos'] | keyvalue" ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
                  <button *ngIf="tipo.key == registro[opcionesReData['clave']]" *ngFor="opcion of tipo" ngbDropdownItem>opcion</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Estoy utilizando un dropdown personalizado que instale por npm pero no esta relacionado con el problema.

Agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

Comment: Hola. No entendí muy bien cual es el problema.

Comment: Creo que no me permite hacer eso, creo que no se pueden mezclar *ngIf y *ngFor en el mismo elemento.

Comment: Es correcto. Te pongo una respuesta a modo ilustrativo de la solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible mezclar `*ngFor` y `*ngIf` en la misma etiqueta. Pero se puede solucionar con `<ng-container>`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="opcion of tipo">

 <button *ngIf="tipo.key == registro[opcionesReData['clave']]" ngbDropdownItem>opcion</button>

</ng-container>
```

Esta etiqueta no se renderiza.

Puedes leer [más aqui](https://profile.es/blog/angular-templates-las-directivas-ng-template-ng-container-y-ngtemplateoutlet/)